# Using JxMaps in JavaFX project

Tags: java, swing, javafx, jxmapviewer, jxmaps

I am developing a Desktop application in Java using JavaFX for the GUI. A vital part of the program consists of a map for which I've decided to use [JxMaps](https://www.teamdev.com/jxmaps) since it being a powerful framework with a very good documentation made it the best option.

However, the problem is that it is integrated in Swing, which I thought shouldn't be an issue since I found the code from [this example](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/embed_swing/jfxpub-embed_swing.htm). In fact, it compiles, but for some reason I get "Application Not Responding". I assume it has to do with this integration as the maps work perfectly when I run them outside the JavaFX application.

My current program looks exactly like this:

**Main.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
        createMap(swingNode);

        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        pane.getChildren().add(swingNode);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Fields Map");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 700, 500));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void createMap(final SwingNode swingNode) {
        final FieldsMap mapView = new FieldsMap();

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> swingNode.setContent(mapView));
    }
}
```

**FieldsMap.java**

```
import com.teamdev.jxmaps.*;
import com.teamdev.jxmaps.swing.MapView;

public class FieldsMap extends MapView {

    public FieldsMap() {
        setOnMapReadyHandler(new MapReadyHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(MapStatus status) {
                // Check if the map is loaded correctly
                if (status == MapStatus.MAP_STATUS_OK) {
                    // Getting the associated map object
                    final Map map = getMap();
                    // Creating a map options object
                    MapOptions options = new MapOptions(map);
                    // Creating a map type control options object
                    MapTypeControlOptions controlOptions = new MapTypeControlOptions(map);
                    // Changing position of the map type control
                    controlOptions.setPosition(ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT);
                    // Setting map type control options
                    options.setMapTypeControlOptions(controlOptions);
                    // Setting map options
                    map.setOptions(options);
                    // Setting the map center
                    map.setCenter(new LatLng(map, 35.91466, 10.312499));
                    // Setting initial zoom value
                    map.setZoom(2.0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This last one being an exact copy of the [Map example in their Github repository](https://github.com/TeamDev-Ltd/JxMaps-Examples/blob/master/src/com/teamdev/jxmaps/examples/MapExample.java).

Finally, the exact output in my console and what I see when I right-click on the java app can be seen here:

[image: Console output + "Application not Responding"]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Vitaly from JxMaps team here. At the moment JxMaps does not support JavaFX. We’re working on implementing JavaFX support in one of the next versions. Drop us a line via email and we’ll inform you, once the version with this feature is out.

Answer (score -1):

Two other options specifically for JavaFX:

http://gluonhq.com/announcing-gluon-maps/

https://github.com/rterp/GMapsFX

I have been using the Gluon Map component for an internal project and so far it meets our requirements.

I haven't used GMapsFX.